# Leather like texture using nodes

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I don't know much of the intricacies of nodes and was wondering how I might go about creating a procedural dark red leathery textured skin for a model I am working on. I don't want to use a UV texture for it.

This is the look I'm going for the skin, I'm currently looking at some tutorials but most haven't had a great result

[image]

The problem I am having is that textures I've tried aren't showing up it just looks red even with increased factors, here is what I have from following a video.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, what have you gotten so far, and where are you having trouble? Are you using cycles or internal? It would also help to add an image that represents what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=cycles+procedural+leather

Comment: @Timaroberts Yeah I'm in cycles, and I've tried quite a bit but nothings really looked remotely like what I want. I was gonna do a image but I figured since I haven't made any progress on it I wouldn't need one

Comment: @PhoenixCreations could you just add some image of what do you expect, some example?

Comment: @LukeD yeah I'll make an edit to my post

Comment: Here: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?278285-Yet-Another-Thread-about-Cycles-Materials&p=2307698&highlight=leather#post2307698 Check brown leather material.

Comment: @PhoenixCreations There is also link to Blend Swap with improved version.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/blender-tutorial-chair-materials/) at step 3.  Or if you are a cgcookie citizen you can find a nice leather [tutorial here](https://cgcookie.com/course/shader-forge/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purely Node Based Materials](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53294/purely-node-based-materials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this has been all sorted, thanks for the suggestions, I finally got the result I wanted. I'll do some modifications but I used a blend swap file and here is the result I've come up with so far.
[image]
Thanks for the help!!!